# Plotting data from an interpolation

Tags: plotting

I have this program

```
f = Interpolation[arw, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Do[wx = Random[Real, {0, 1.5695}];
fwx = f[wx];
Print[fwx, "  ", wx], {1000}]
```

I want to plot the distribution of these data. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use `Print`, don't use `Do`; Look up `Table` and the various flavours of `ListPlot`.

Comment: `Random` is obsolete; the same goal can be accomplished with `RandomReal[{0, 1.5695}]`. Also, what is `arw`? Can you describe what you want to accomplish in context? You can edit your question using the "edit" button under the question itself.

Comment: [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html), perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Using your `f` you might try :

```
points = f /@ RandomReal[{0, 1.5695},100];
DiscretePlot[PDF[EmpiricalDistribution[points], x], {x, points}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why the `PDF[EmpiricalDistribution[...]]` part? Shouldn't `ListPlot[points]` be sufficient? Or better, something like `points = {#, f[#]}& /@ RandomReal[{0, 1.5695}, 100]; ListPlot[points]`? I am not entirely convinced that the OP's mention of a distribution really refers to a probability distribution; of course, OP should weigh in and explain.